# ISS.0081.9002 Cannot perform operation without Write ACL privileges on a service

Tags: shell, curl, webmethods

I am invoking a webMethods service from unix shell via `curl`

```
curl --user USER_NAME:USER_PASSWORD --url http://IS_SERVER:IS_PORT/invoke/wm.server.access:aclAssign?target=XYZ&writeaclgroup=Administrators
```

But it is throwing an exception saying

```
[ISS.0081.9002] Cannot perform operation without Write ACL privileges on XYZ
```

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the message is pretty clear - if you want to change the write ACL, your user (USER_NAME) has to be in current write ACL group...

Without a modification, the group is `Default` and Default ACL is defined as:

[image: webMethods Integration Server Default ACL]

Also your command was not working for me I had to use POST

```
curl --user Administrator:manage --data 'target=betlista:aclTest&writeaclgroup=Developers' --url http://localhost:5555/invoke/wm.server.access:aclAssign
```

I tried with version 9.8.

On the other hand, the `wm.server.access:aclAssign` can be executed only by Administrators..I tried for a while, but I was not able to reproduce your problem, still I believe it's clear, you just didn't share all info.

Comment: `USER_NAME`, `USER_PASSWORD`, `IS_SERVER`, `IS_PORT` all are variables. I(the user) is listed under Administrators ACL. So I can directly execute `wm.server.access:aclAssign`. I am using wM 8.8.

Comment: Your comment didn't make it more clear. We understood, that IS_PORT is not your port number... Is it working for you or not?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to invoke your service directly through an http request. Usually it's better to expose the flow service as a web service. Anyways, here's something that could work:

1) Open the flow service, that you are trying to post a request to, inside webMethods Designer.

2) Make sure that the flow service is in "**Lock For Edit**" (editable mode).

3) You should see this in the properties pane of the flow service:

[image]

4) Double click on the "..." button:

[image]

5) The following window will open:

[image]

6) Now change the "Execution ACL" and the "Write ACL" to "**Anonymous**" and try your http request again.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Actually the code written in the question runs in a batch job from Unix shell script. This runs on every package of a repository, so it is not possible to do it individually for each package.

Comment: Does my answer solve the exception message you were having? If so then the original question is answered. The problem you are having with running your shell script for every package is a different kind of problem and so should be in a new stackoverflow question. It involves understanding what your intentions are to do this and asking the community if you have the correct strategy to achieve whatever you are trying to achieve.